# how to enable https tls on kubernetes GCE

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-security

I successfully deployed my web app on kubernetes in Google cloud. It is serving via http. I followed all guides on how to add ssl certificate and it was added according to Google cloud console however, it only work as http , when you try to access the web app as HTTPS. the browser says "This site can’t be reached"

my ingress YAML looks like this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: no-rules-map
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: testsecret
  backend:
    serviceName: s1
    servicePort: 80
```

for Secret

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: [crt]
  tls.key: [key]
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: testsecret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Comment: You also need a secret, called testsecret, that has 2 keys in its data field- tls.crt and tls.key- containing the requisite encoded data.

Comment: It is already added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this command to upload my ssl certificate

```
kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --key=/tmp/tls.key --cert=/tmp/tls.crt
```

instead of yaml file Secret below and it works better. At least for Google Cloud

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: [crt]
  tls.key: [key]
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: testsecret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Make sure when you go to `Kubernates Engine -> Configuration` in Google Cloud Console that your secret type is  `Secret: kubernetes.io/tls` and not only `Secret`. when you create your secret using yaml it is created as secret only and not Secret: kubernetes.io/tls.

For more information you can take a look at these following links:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce#backend-https

[enter link description here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#remarks